# How to overlie bar charts in nvd3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I want to display one bar chart on top of another one.

**Reason:**

> I am showing a base consumption on a certain day, but also the overall
>   value.

I don't want a bar chart next to another but on top of one.

So far, I draw a line with pure d3.js  on top of the bar, which brings a lot complexity and handling edge cases on my own.

[image]

The problem: I am using a multibarchart with nvd3.js, because I sometimes display more than one range of value in my chart. **So for one or more series inside this chart, I want to display another bar chart on top.**

**Is there a better solution for this?**

Comment: Do you want to make a stack chart http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208

Comment: You can do a stack bar chart with nvd3 as well.  This is what I would suggest.

Comment: But what happens when I want to show two bars next to each other, and, one on top of each other each? So I have two different values each day, and I want to show a baseload on top of each bar for each day...